# permission url callback on-login using custom HTML button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook button which refreshes my url `on-login`

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_about_me,user_photos" on-login="window.location = 'http://myDomain.com';">Login</fb:login-button>
```

But if i dont want to use the standard facebook button and decide to use my own markup with javascript
i seem to having a hard time getting the callback on login
heres my attempt, any suggestions or help is always appreciated
thanks

```
function fb_oAuth(){
    FB.ui({
            method: "permissions.request", 
            "perms": 'email, user_about_me, user_photos'
        } , function(response) { 
        console.log(response); 
        /* if (response.session) {
                    window.location.href = 'http://www.myDomain.com';
                }  */
        });

        /*  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
                if (response.session) {
                    window.location.href = 'http://www.myDomain.com';
                } else {
                    // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
                }
        }); */

});

// HTML button
<a href="#" onClick="fb_oAuth(); event.preventDefault();">Login with Facebook</a>
```

Comment: Don’t use FB.ui and method: "permissions.request" – use FB.login instead. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FB.login as a method permissions.request method wont work for your senerio. Check FB dev. docs for more information.

Comment: that with `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(resp) {
        window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/custom_page.php';
    });
};` did the trick